# Ionic 2 scroll event

Tags: ionic2

I have an ion-scroll component.
I'm trying to execute some code during scrolling. In Ionic 1 this was possible using the on-scroll attribute and passing a function.

The documentation is also missing. Is there a built in way in Ionic 2 to detect scrolling, or do I have to fall back on adding my own event handlers using jQuery or window scroll event?

Comment: this is the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186715/3786343

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here: [“On-scroll” not working in](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/on-scroll-not-working-in-ion-content/42041)

Using the `"addScrollEventListener"` inside `"ngAfterViewChecked"`.

Comment: Current solution https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/scrolling-event-in-ion-content/55563/3

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `addScrollEventListener` method of the Scroll component, like so:

```
this.scroll.addScrollEventListener((event) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

**Your HTML:**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="no-scroll">
    <ion-scroll></ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

**Your Typescript:**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Scroll} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    @ViewChild(Scroll) scroll: Scroll;

    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.scroll.addScrollEventListener(this.onScroll);
    }

    onScroll(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, how to listen for scrollStarted & scrollEnd event for ion-scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-rc4-addscrolllistener/73145/16?u=kamleshappster

```
this.content.ionScroll.subscribe(($event) => {
 this.scrollAmount = $event.scrollTop;
});
```