# OnScroll event Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Picking up when a user scroll on Ionic 2 is confusing me. I basically want to say, when a user scrolls down the page, do something.

Any examples would be great.

UPDATE:

I have this in my constructor, so when the page scrolls I want to close the keyboard, due to it being left open and no other way to close.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Content } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

export class SearchPage {

  @ViewChild(Content)
  content:Content;

  constructor(public keyboard: Keyboard, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public apiAuthentication: ApiAuthentication, private http: Http) {

    this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.keyboard.close();
    });
  }
}
```

However I get this error `Cannot read property 'ionScroll' of undefined` am i putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: I assume you have an `<ion-content>` tag in your view? And you probably have to subscribe on the event in one of ionic's view life cycles instead of the constructor.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can subscribe to content events.

Content has [3 output events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#output-events):

- **ionScroll**        Emitted on every scroll event.
- **ionScrollEnd**     Emitted when scrolling ends.
- **ionScrollStart**   Emitted when the scrolling first starts.

Listen to an event:

```
@ViewChild(Content)
content: Content;
// ...
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.content.ionScrollEnd.subscribe((data)=>{
    //... do things
  });
}
```

Or do it from the DOM:

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">
```

**For Ionic 4**

```
<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">
```

Comment: Thankyou for this! I have updated the question with an error i am gettign

Comment: Did you get the child component `Content`?

Comment: Yes, I have update again to show main aspects of .ts file

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: not works in ios, do you have other idea? or solution?

Comment: `[scrollEvents]="true"` gives error. Can't bind to 'scrollEvents' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-content'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngOnInit method to register the scroll event :

```
ngOnInit() {
   if (this.content) {
      this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((data)=>
        this.keyboard.close();
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When inside a custom directive try with something like this:

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.myElement, 'scroll', (event) => {
        // Do something with 'event'
        console.log(this.myElement.scrollTop);
    });
}
```