# ionic 3 with angular 4.3.6 - no scroll events

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, scroll

I'm not getting ANY scoll events in Ionic 3.6.0 using

I've tried Hostlistener, Observable.fromEvent and plain Javascript

```
 @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) private scroll(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
  Observable.fromEvent(document, 'scroll').subscribe(e => console.log(e))
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Anybody has the same issue?

Comment: Ionic does not officially support Angular `4.3.6` yet. The latest version recommended is `4.1.3.`

Comment: still that shouldn't break since plain javascript didn't work too. Plus i've started a super template ionic project and it doesn't work there too

Comment: Nevermind then! Maybe this helps your use-case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186715/6184203