# How to detect scroll using Ionic 2+ and Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular7

Is it possible to detect when the window is scrolled?

I have tried adding `HostListener`:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onScroll() {
   console.log('scroll');
}
```

And I have tried using `Renderer2`:

```
this.renderer.listen(
   'window',
   'scroll',
   (evt) => {
      console.log('scroll');
   }
);
```

Neither work.

Comment: i edit code plz check

Comment: @KiranMistry It still did not work. Thanks though.

Comment: i edit post again please hava a look for ionic

Answer (score 2):

in your `html` file add this

```
<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true"></ion-content>
```

in your your `.ts` file add this

```
@HostListener('ionScroll', ['$event']) onScroll(event){
    console.log(event.detail.scrollTop)
    console.log('im scrolling')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can detect the scroll with below code, just as your first code snippet..

```
 @HostListener('window:scroll')
 onWindowScroll():void {
   let isScrolled = window.scrollY > this.heightToCompare;
   if (isScrolled !== false) {
      //  do what you want  
   } 
 }
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question this does not work. I have added a breakpoint and console log and this does not trigger. Maybe it's because Ionic.

Comment: @jrquick its not working because ,  you should not be setting overflow-x: hidden inside the body or should not set height:100%  . ionic for some reason  is auto setting height:100%

Comment: @jrquick also this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186489/onscroll-event-ionic-2