# Update DOM in scroll event Ionic 2/3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I want to do a progress bar when user scrolls down. When it's down all the way, the bar is 100% width.

The problem is the "per" value is not updated to view on scroll event

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235949/ionic-2-scroll-event) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186489/onscroll-event-ionic-2), but none worked

Template

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>{‌{title}} ({‌{code}})</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header

<ion-content>
<ion-toolbar style="position: fixed; opacity: 0.8; z-index: 1" *ngIf="readProgress">
    <div id="bar" color="primary">{‌{per}} 30%</div>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-content>
```

TS FILE

```
this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((data) => {
  if (data.scrollTop < 1) {
    this.readProgress = false;
    this.title='Not Scrolling';
  } else if (data.scrollTop > 0) {
    this.readProgress = true;
    this.title='Scrolling';
  }
  this.per = data.scrollTop;  
});
```

Comment: Whats the problem with your current code? The observable doesn't fire? The scrollTop doesn't affect the dom?

Comment: The scrollTop is not affecting the dom. The variable 'per' is fed the value of scrollTop which should be displayed here

 <div id="bar" color="primary">{‌{per}} 30%</div>

When I scroll I need the value of scrollTop/current scroll position to be displayed but its not

Comment: I am not sure but try calling changedetectionref.detectchanges because the change might be outside of ngzone. Basically it doesn't detect that it changed

Comment: Thanks misha130, Its working

Comment: Write an answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by making Angular detect changes after the 'per' value changes

### 1. Imports

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
```

### 2. Constructor

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      }
```

### 3. On Scroll Event

```
   this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((data) => {
          if (data.scrollTop < 1) {
            this.readProgress = false;
            this.title='Not Scrolling';
          } else if (data.scrollTop > 0) {
            this.readProgress = true;
            this.title='Scrolling';
          }
          this.per = data.scrollTop;  
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks to @misha130