# Event "ionScroll" in ion-scroll of Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ion-scroll

well, I'm want fire `ionScroll` in directive `ion-scroll`, but it does not work.

Have idea how I can work with this???

API: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/

Comment: I don't see ionScroll in the [API](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/).

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/

Comment: you said you want to "fire ionScroll" but the API doesn't show that event is what I am trying to say.  What are you drying to do with the ion-scroll directive?

Comment: I'm solved it with pure DOM, but may be is have another way...

Answer (score 1):

I will post this in case you or someone else is still looking for an answer.

There is `ion-infinite-scroll` you could use but it only applies to the `ion-content` you can use it if it suites you.

However, if you really want to get event from `ion-scroll`, you may want to try something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42176764/4084776

If you want to check when you reach the bottom of the scroll you could add a dummy element and check if it is near the bottom of the scroll. See the example below.

```js
  ...
  @ViewChild(Scroll) ionScroll: Scroll;
  @ViewChild("endOfScroll") endOfScroll: ElementRef;
  updating: Boolean = false;
  private threshold: number = 0.01; //1% This is similar to ion-infinite-scroll threshold 
  ...
  ionViewDidLoad() { 
      this.ionScroll.addScrollEventListener(this.scrollHandler.bind(this));
  }
  ...
  scrollHandler(evenman){
    let endOfScroll = this.endOfScroll.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    let ionScroll = this.ionScroll._scrollContent.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    let clearance = 1 - ionScroll.bottom/endOfScroll.bottom;
    if(clearance <= this.threshold){
      this.updating = true;
      // DO your work here
      console.log(JSON.stringify({fen: endOfScroll.bottom, lis: ionScroll.bottom}));
      this.updating = false;

    }
  }
...
```

```html
...
      <ion-scroll scrollY="true">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let machann of lisMachann.lisMachann  let endeks = index" [class.active]="endeks == endeksKlik">
            <ion-item (click)="ouveFenet(endeks)">
            ...
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options side="left">
            ...
            </ion-item-options>
          </ion-item-sliding>
          <ion-item *ngIf="updating">
            <ion-spinner class="loading-center"></ion-spinner>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <div #endOfScroll></div>
      </ion-scroll>
...
```